# Rails4: Ajax.request (edit) not returning data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am sending a `$.ajax()` *edit/update* request for editing a Group record, which should render json data ( `render :json, @data.to_json` ) 
I am only getting the xor object upon checking the **Ajax** success.

The data is correctly setup on the server, but in the success callback function is stated as undefined.

Which is quite weird, as I quite duplicated the same code for new/create and it's running fine.

Here is the *edit/update* code:

```
        ===============================  HTML ====================================
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            ...
        </head>
        <body class="<%= controller_name -%> <%= action_name -%>">
            ....
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT -->
            <div id="page-content">
                <div id='wrap'>

                    <div id= "groupRole-tableTools" class="options">   
                          <div id="groupRole-addTool" class="btn-group visible">
                            <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">...</button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                              <li><a id="group-addTool" href="/groups/new">Add a group</a></li>
                              ...
                            </ul>
                         </div>
                    </div> 

                    <div id="groupRole-lineTools" class="options hidden">   
                       ...            
                       <a data-toggle="modal" data-accessible-id="#" id="groupRole-editTool" href="#groupRoleModal">...</a>                    
                       ...
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body collapse in">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered datatables" id="groups">...</table>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="groupModal" tabindex="-1" access_level="dialog" aria-labelledby="groupModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> <!--wrap -->
            </div> <!-- page-content -->
            <!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->

            <script src="/assets/administration/groups.index.js></script>        
            <script src="/assets/administration/init.js></script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

And here is the *groups.index.js* loaded with the page:

```
  =================  groups.index.js ===================

        $(document).ready(function() {
          console.log("groups.index.js");

          $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
          var ajaxUrl = "http://" + window.location.host + "/groups.json";

            $.ajax( {
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "GET",
                "url": ajaxUrl,
                "success": function (data) {

                    var table = $('#groups').DataTable( {  
                        select: true,
                        data: data.rows,
                        columns: [...],
                        columnDefs: [...]
                        ...
                    } );
                    table
                        .on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
                            var rowData = table.rows( indexes ).data().toArray();
                            var companyId = rowData[0].company_id;
                            groupId = rowData[0].group_id;
                            var groupName = rowData[0].group_name;
                        // hide add tool
                            $("#groupRole-addTool" ).toggleClass( "hidden", "visible" );
                        // show line tool
                            $("#groupRole-lineTools" ).toggleClass( "hidden", "visible" ); 
                        // set line tools data in DOM
                            $("#groupRole-editTool").attr("data-accessible-id", accessibleId );
                            $("#groupRole-editTool").attr("data-accessible-url", accessibleUrl );
                         } )
                         .on( 'deselect', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
                         // hide line tool
                           $("#groupRole-lineTools" ).toggleClass( "hidden", "visible" );
                         // show add tool
                           $("#groupRole-addTool" ).toggleClass( "hidden", "visible" );
                         } );

                    // Handle EDIT GROUP tool click event
                    $('#groupRole-editTool').on('click', function(e) {
                      var itemId = $(this).data('accessible-id');
                      var ajaxUrl = "http://" + window.location.host + accessibleUrl + itemId + "/edit";
                      e.preventDefault();
                      e.stopPropagation();
                      // get EDIT FORM in modal content
                      $.ajax({
                        "dataType": 'html',
                        "type": "GET",
                        "url": ajaxUrl,
                        "success": function (code_html, _status) {
                          $('#groupModal').modal('show');
                          $("#groupModal div.modal-content").html(code_html);
                          $("#edit_group").on("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, _status){
                            console.log("data: "+JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));   # data undefined !!!!
                            if (data["error"]) {
                              // errors back from server
                              $("#modalGroupAlert" ).removeClass('alert-info');
                              $("#modalGroupAlert" ).addClass('alert-danger');
                              $("#modalGroupAlert span" ).replaceWith( data["html"] );
                              $("#modalGroupAlert" ).toggleClass( "hidden", "visible" ); 
                            } else {
                              // no errors
                              table.row.data(data["row"]).draw();
                              $('#groupModal').modal('hide');
                            }
                          });
                        }
                      });
                    });  

                    // Handle ADD GROUP tool click event
                    $('#groupRole-addTool').on('click', function(e) {
                      var ajaxUrl = "http://" + window.location.host + "/groups/new";
                      e.preventDefault();
                      e.stopPropagation();
                      // get NEW FORM in modal content
                      $.ajax({
                        "dataType": 'html',
                        "type": "GET",
                        "url": ajaxUrl,
                        "success": function (code_html, _status) {
                          $('#groupModal').modal('show');
                          $("#groupModal div.modal-content").html(code_html);
                          $("#new_group").on("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, _status){
                            console.log("data: "+JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));     # data defined !!!!
                            if (data["error"]) {
                              // errors back from server
                              $("#modalGroupAlert" ).removeClass('alert-info');
                              $("#modalGroupAlert" ).addClass('alert-danger');
                              $("#modalGroupAlert span" ).replaceWith( data["html"] );
                              $("#modalGroupAlert" ).toggleClass( "hidden", "visible" ); 
                            } else {
                              // no errors
                              table.row.add(data["row"]).draw();
                              $('#groupModal').modal('hide');
                            }
                          });
                        }
                      });
                    });  

                }
```

What bothers me is that the *ADD GROUP tool click event* is correctly handling the **Ajax** request to fill in the modal with html, and then correctly requesting  the json data once the create is done.

but with  similar code, the **Ajax** edit request , is also filling up the model with html form, but once updated , the data back is undefined. The update is OK , the son data correctly setup , the **Ajax** request is also successful, but no data back. Only the xor object.

**UPDATE 1 =========**

I updated the ajax:success parameters ( they were wrong)  to

```
$("#edit_group").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, _status, xor){..}
```

and checked the xor object...  the return code is 204 , which means NO CONTENT ..
why  a Rails 4  PATCH update is responding with 204 ???

```
xhr: {
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "",
  "status": 204,
  "statusText": "No Content"
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it's not an issue related with the edit form method... I'll check it stating a method: PUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer : this is a NORMAL BEHAVIOr with update, client is not supposed to receive anything else that the status 204.
However , I can bypass it by writing :

```
render(json: @data.to_json , status: 200)
```

which forces the status to be 200 and son data is sent back